# como faco para resolver o erro Undefined property: stdClass::

Tags: php

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\peliculas\Model\Cliente.class.php on line 79`

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in C:\xampp\htdocs\peliculas\Model\Cliente.class.php on line 80`

como faco para resolver esse erro a linha em questão do erro a 79 e a 80 são:

`$_SESSION['nomeCliente'] = $row->nome;
$_SESSION['idCliente'] = $row->id;`

```
public function logarCliente(){
      $c = new Conexao();

      $sql = mysqli_query($c->conectar(), "SELECT email, senha FROM clientes WHERE email = '{$this->getEmail()}' AND senha = '{$this->getSenha()}' AND ativo = 1");
      $c->desconectar();

      if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        $row = $sql->fetch_object();
        $_SESSION['nomeCliente'] = $row->nome;
        $_SESSION['idCliente'] = $row->id;
        $_SESSION['logado'] = true;

        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É impossível extrair `id` e `nome` da *query*. Isso porque no select só foram especificadas as colunas `email` e `senha`.

Você precisa alter o `select` ou escolher os campos corretamente.

**ACHO** que você pretendia escrever a *query* assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($c->conectar(), "SELECT id, nome FROM clientes 
                                     WHERE email = '{$this->getEmail()}' 
                                     AND senha = '{$this->getSenha()}' 
                                     AND ativo = 1");
```

Comment: nuss eu nem vi isso obg pela resp